# Could not find Stored Procedure

Tags: .net, stored-procedures

I have inherited a website that is apparently referencing a stored procedure "XYZ" and when the site runs I get an error message saying Could not find stored procedure "XYZ". All this makes sense because inside MSSQL Studio, this sproc does in fact not exist. HOWEVER, I have no idea where this is getting referenced inside the solution. I have done a search of the entire solution for "XYZ" and it says it's not found. Where can I go to find where this stored procedure is being referenced and eliminate the problem. Thanks in advance for any help/advice

Answer (score 2):

Your store procedure `XYZ` maybe called by another stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

If it isn't called directly, it's called indirectly

How to search all code definitions...

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%XYZ%'
```

Comment: We're running sql2000 but I used SELECT * FROM syscomments WHERE text LIKE '%XYZ%' and got no results...

Comment: @Logan W: sorry for late answer: you get multiple rows in syscomments for long procedures because the text column is nvarchar(4000). You'd have to consider an XYZ string spanning the 4k boundaries

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is being referenced from another stored procedure, if you want you can just create a dummy stored procedure to "quick fix it" while you research more, a good tool is to use the SQL Server Profiler, that way you can see whats being executed on the SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your schema name is in the connection string.

Also you can use [this](http://shahanayyub.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/find-procedure-in-all-databases/) to find procedure in all databases.